# Wordpress: styling excerpt/content multiple times

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I'm new to wordpress and PHP, and after a while trying to code a magazine style layout using multiple loops, a friend turned me onto styling one loop with multiple post appearances using children.

Example:

```
.hentry:first-child {
background-color: gray;
height: 460px;
}
```

This saves me having to categorize and uncategorize posts to get them to appear from most recent onward but with their correct styling.

The parent/child concept worked great, until I tried to style the .entry-content class which is applied to the excerpts on all posts.

I have tried:

```
.entry-content:first-child {
<--styles-->
}
```

But no luck. The only thing that appears to make a difference is styling the .entry-content class itself, but this obviously won't do since the three appearances I have going are quite different in size and so forth.

A few people from the Wordpress Answers website seemed to think I would have better luck at Stack Overflow.

Any suggestions? Framework in progress (very in progress) is at: http://piquantblog.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
.hentry:first-child .entry-content{}
```

if you want to target the entry-content in first hentry

Comment: Perfect! It appears I need another crash course in css syntax -_-.
Thanks!